# Verifying if method was called with Moq

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have the following problem while UnitTesting C# code with Moq framework:

I'm unable to check how many times given method(*TestCaseExecutions.Add()*) is executed. Execution counter is always zero.

Under "PROBLEM IS HERE" comment there are two lines marked as "1" and "2".

"1" is responsible for iterating *TestCaseExecutions.Add(TestCaseExecution)* call counter.
"2" is needed for operations on this table in method *SomeMethodThatUsesMockedContext(mockContext.Object)*, without it any linq queries will throw null pointer exception.

After commenting out "2" line and *SomeMethodThatUsesMockedContext* method and adding

```
mockContext.Object.TestCaseExecutions.Add(new TestCaseExecution());
```

just before *Verify* method resulted with PASS.

How do I get around this problem and why using line "2" somehow neutralizes line "1"?

```
[Test()]
public void SomeTest()
{
    //Internal counters.
    int saveChanges = 0;
    int AddedExecutions = 0;

    //Mock DatabaseContext
    var mockContext = new Mock<TestRunsEntities>();
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges()).Callback(() => saveChanges++);
    ...

    //Mock of one of it's tables
    var mockTestCaseExecution = new Mock<DbSet<TestCaseExecution>>();

    //PROBLEM IS HERE (I think)
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.TestCaseExecutions.Add(It.IsAny<TestCaseExecution>())).Callback(() => addExecution++); //1
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.TestCaseExecutions).Returns(mockTestCaseExecution.Object); //2


    //Inside this method Save(), and TestCaseExecutions.Add(TestCaseExecution ex) are called.
    //I have checked in debug mode that they are called once for my test scenario.
    SomeMethodThatUsesMockedContext(mockContext.Object);

    //After execution, saveChanges is equal to 1 as expected but AddedExecutions is equal to 0

    //This step fails.
    mockContext.Verify(x => x.TestCaseExecutions.Add(It.IsAny<TestCaseExecution>()), Times.Once());

    ...
}
```

EDIT WITH SOLUTION:

Problem lies in line marked as "1" and in calling of Verify.
I have used incorrect context for these lines.

Before:

```
mockContext.Setup(x => x.TestCaseExecutions.Add(It.IsAny<TestCaseExecution>())).Callback(() => addExecution++); //1
```

After:

```
mockTestCaseExecution.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TestCaseExecution>())).Callback(() => addExecution++);
```

Same goes for Verify method in the last line.

Comment: Is the `TestCaseExecutions.Add` method virtual?

Comment: @galenus, I think it's [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.add(v=vs.113).aspx), so, yes, it's virtual

Comment: Yeah, it's method generated from Entity Framework context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the line `1` you setup the mock, but line `2` overrides the whole mock, so now `mockContext.TestCaseExecutions` returns `mockTestCaseExecution.Object` - mock that hasn't been configured.

You call `Add` on `mockTestCaseExecution` object, so you should set up there.

```
//Mock of one of it's tables
var mockTestCaseExecution = new Mock<DbSet<TestCaseExecution>>();
mockTestCaseExecution.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TestCaseExecution>())).Callback(() => addExecution++); //1

mockContext.Setup(c => c.TestCaseExecutions).Returns(mockTestCaseExecution.Object); //2
```

Comment: Thanks! I have missed such an obvious thing! Changed it and it worked like a charm! Will add edit with changes to code :)